# Multiple field modal input dialog in Javascript

Tags: javascript, user-interface, input, dojo, modal-dialog

I am working on a Javascript widget that allows users to set the value of attributes.  By default the user enters the values by typing them into a textfield (html input) but I need to allow the user to changes the means of input into a slider control.  When the user changes to a slider control I need to allow them to set the min and max value for the slider (and maybe make some other choices).  Since I need the user to enter multiple values I cannot use the prompt dialog.  What could I do instead?  We are using Dojo in this project so a Dojo solution would be great but I am open to using any other libraries that play well with Dojo.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Well initially I thought about some options such as popping up another window or a div that contained the needed text fields but this seemed very clumsy. I did a web search and a search on Stackoverflow to see if this was a question that had been asked on this or some other resource, but I found very little.  Then I looked through Dojo documentation for a widget that might fulfill my needs.  Since my ideas seemed bad and I assumed that this is a challenge others were likely to have solved I decided to post here before trying something that I did think would yield a good solution.

Comment: Good answer, but I fail to see why popping up a div is a clumsy solution? dojotoolkit has a dialog box implementation

Comment: Ah okay I think I found the dialog box you were talking about, thanks!  Also, thanks for the link that was a good read.